# How to keep count of different object instances in android app?

Tags: java, android, class

I am making an app that contains a MainActivity with a recycler view that contains a list of birds. When you click on the bird it goes to a details activity with the bird info. (Works fine)

The details activity also has a button that increases a count. The problem I am having is that I don't know how I can access the instance of the bird from the details activity to keep track of that count.

Here is the Bird class; This is where I should keep a count variable?

```
public class Bird {

    // Variables
    private String scientificName;
    private String commonName;
    private String description;
    private String numberImage;
    private int count;

    // Defaults Constructor
    public Bird() {

    }

    // Constructor with parameters
    public Bird(String scientificName, String commonName, String description, String numberImage) {
        this.scientificName = scientificName;
        this.commonName = commonName;
        this.description = description;
        this.numberImage = numberImage;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    // Getters
    public String getScientificName() {
        return scientificName;
    }

    public String getCommonName() {
        return commonName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getNumberImage() {
        return numberImage;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setScientificName(String scientificName) {
        this.scientificName = scientificName;
    }

    public void setCommonName(String commonName) {
        this.commonName = commonName;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setNumberImage(String numberImage) {
        this.numberImage = numberImage;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Here is the detail activity

```
public class BookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView birdImage;
    private TextView birdCommonName;
    private TextView birdSciName;
    private TextView birdDesc;
    private TextView birdCount;
    private Button countButton;
    int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

        // Views
        birdCommonName = findViewById(R.id.com_name);
        birdSciName = findViewById(R.id.sci_name);
        birdDesc = findViewById(R.id.description);
        birdImage = findViewById(R.id.bird_image);
        birdCount = findViewById(R.id.bird_count);
        countButton = findViewById(R.id.count_button);

        // Receive data
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String commonName = intent.getExtras().getString("CommonName");
        String sciName = intent.getExtras().getString("SciName");
        String desc = intent.getExtras().getString("Description");
        int img = intent.getExtras().getInt("Image");

        // Set values
        birdCommonName.setText(commonName);
        birdSciName.setText(sciName);
        birdDesc.setText(desc);
        birdImage.setImageResource(img);
    }

    public void plusCount() {
        birdCount.setText(count);
    }
}

``
```

Comment: First of all, where you are setting the adapter

Comment: I set the adapter on the main activity recyclerview

Comment: whenever you are going to your detailed activity, pass the object to there. Then, get the current count from that object and increase the count. Then set the new value at object count value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a raw bundled bird data to a details activity and then simply binding it to UI. That's the simplest approach to have that type of read-only components.

In case you want to make this data "live", operational and stateful, preserving Android best architecture practices, you should address one of the next approaches:

- Use an ORM backed by a database ([Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room), [Realm](https://realm.io/)
  file-backed/in-memory) in order to consistently query and write your
  data in different parts of the application (and preferably combine
  that with [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture), [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging),
  [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation))
- Use a [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) / [Local storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) approach to do basically the
  same things but with custom serialization/deserialization pipelines
  (simpler learning curve but much lower flexibility / scalability / performance / features set)
- Use a single page application approach with a shared ViewModel layer,
  responsible for data CRUD and utilizing one of the previous options or completely in-memory repository.

And please, do not try to pass objects by any kind of reference between your application components, especially UI ones. Android state handling is complex and that approach will definitely fail.